# array mixed with objects and more arrays

Tags: php, php-5.3

var_dump of my array shows up like this. I want to get the count of my_options in the array. note that index 2 has no options. How' I go about doing that

```
var_dump($myVar);


array
  0 => 
    object(app\models\Product)[209]
      protected '_Nested' => 
        array
          empty
      protected '_Sibling' => 
        array
          empty
      protected '_class' => string 'app\models\Customer' (length=18)
      protected '_data' => 
        array
          '_id' => int 345543
          'customer_name' => string 'John Dee' (length=14)
          'Sibling' => 
            array
              ...
          'my_options' => 
            array
              ...
          'Nesting' => 
            array
              ...
          'image' => string 'img.jpg' (length=35)
          'inventory' => 
            array
              ...
          'name' => string 'papa john' (length=35)
          'price' => float 26
          'status' => int 1
1 => 
    object(app\models\Product)[209]
      protected '_Nested' => 
        array
          empty
      protected '_Sibling' => 
        array
          empty
      protected '_class' => string 'app\models\Customer' (length=18)
      protected '_data' => 
        array
          '_id' => int 89237
          'customer_name' => string 'Linda Arap' (length=14)
          'Sibling' => 
            array
              ...
          'my_options' => 
            array
              ...
          'Nesting' => 
            array
              ...
          'image' => string 'img2.jpg' (length=35)
          'inventory' => 
            array
              ...
          'name' => string 'Pizza Hut' (length=35)
          'price' => float 26
          'status' => int 1
2 => 
    object(app\models\Product)[209]
      protected '_Nested' => 
        array
          empty
      protected '_Sibling' => 
        array
          empty
      protected '_class' => string 'app\models\Customer' (length=18)
      protected '_data' => 
        array
          '_id' => int 89237
          'customer_name' => string 'Linda Arap' (length=14)
          'Sibling' => 
            array
              ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`_data` is a protected variable so you won't be able to access it from outside the object. You'll need to use (or create) a `getData()` method that accesses`$this->_data`. Just call that method and you'll have access to the options array.

Example method that accesses _data and returns my_options all in one:

```
public function getMyOptions() {
  return $this->_data['my_options'];
}
```

Which can be invoked with something like:

```
$product instanceof app\models\Product;
$myOptions = $product->getMyOptions();
```

---

Also, it looks like you're using a model (possibly orm) class. I would imagine it has built-in methods to access the data array. Common methods to access `my_options` would be:

```
$options = $product->my_options; // via magic methods
$options = $product->get('my_options');
$options = $product->getField('my_options');
```

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I wouldn't let a little [syntactic sugar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar) like [property visibility](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php) get between me and my data.

### How do I access a private or protected property of an object?

With [ReflectionProperty](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionproperty.php) why of course =)

This should do the trick:

```
$my_options_count = array_map(function ($object) {
    $reflect = new ReflectionObject($object);
    foreach ($reflect->getProperties() as $prop)
         if ($prop->name == '_data') {
             $prop->setAccessible(true);
             $data = $prop->getValue($object);
            if (array_key_exists('my_options', $data))
                if (is_array($my_options = $data['my_options']))
                    return count($my_options);
         }
   return 0;
}, $myVar);
```

$my_options_count will now show 0 for the records without a my_options or the number of options for each record. If you were after the total my options from all the records then  [array_sum](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php) is your friend =)

```
$my_options_total = array_sum($my_options_count);
```

Never say never and always keep trying. Njoy!